# Websites quit resolving

Tags: ubuntu, host-name-resolution

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server which is running VestaCP will no longer resolve my websites. I can connect to my VestaCP control panel via IP, but not via hostname anymore. All my websites show this error in Goolge Chrome:

> ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Here is my /etc/hosts files

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
208.110.93.18   hosting.prenticenetwork.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
208.110.93.18 hosting.prenticenetwork.com hosting.prenticenetwork.com
```

Comment: Can you include the output of the following commands as edits to your question please?  `cat /etc/resolv.conf`  `sudo iptables -L -n -v`  `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8`

Comment: It's also unclear where you're testing this from.  Are you using your own computer or your server to try and access the sites?

Comment: The machine in question is a remote server. So I remembered that I did an update to BIND9 and told it to keep the original configuration file. After checking the BIND9 service I noticed that there are access denied messages to each VestaCP .db file. I believe this is my problem, and will post any updates. I am not sure how to re-allow access as the permissions look okay to me.

Comment: Include those errors and also check syslog for apparmor errors?